# How to implement rounded bottomAppbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-bottomappbar

I want to create a rounded Bottomappbar like this one.

Rounded BottomAppBar:

[image: 1]

But it appears like this... Coded BottomAppBar:

[image: 2]
How do I get rid of that white portion?

````
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
        topRight: Radius.circular(25),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:20.0),
        child: BottomAppBar(
    
   shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
   child: new Row(
        
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
    ),
    color: Colors.blueGrey,
    ),
      )
    ); ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App bar widget has a shape property and that's what you should use to get desired results, change your code to this

```
BottomAppBar(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
        topRight: Radius.circular(25),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
      ),
    ),
   ... //Your codes
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks! But I want to keep the Circular Notched rectangle as well with the floating button in center. So is it possible to set shape to RoundedRectangleBorder annd CircularNotchedRectangle at same time

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar. Check out this...it may be helpful for you! If not tell me I will find another

Comment: I used shape: AutomaticNotchedShape( RoundedRectangleBorder(), StadiumBorder()). It did what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

As @Jagadish suggested I used `Shape: RoundedRectangleBorder`  to get rounded BottomAppBar.
However to get notched bar I used:

```
    shape: AutomaticNotchedShape(
RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25),
 ),
StadiumBorder(),
    ),
   ... //Codes=
  ),
```

This also gives a notch for Extended Floating Action Button and (I think) for Buttons with diff shapes.